# MultipleSelectorRow customization

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I'm trying to customize background of controller presented by MultipleSelectorRow, but I cannot.

```
  <<< MultipleSelectorRow<String>("select") { row in
    row.options = values
    row.onPresentCallback = { _, to in
     let backgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (self.tableView?.bounds.size.width)!, height: (self.tableView?.bounds.size.height)!))
     backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
     to.tableView?.backgroundView = backgroundView
    }
  }
```

This doesn't works because to.tableView is nil when the callback is fired.

I think that is not possible to modify the controller without modifications on Eureka library

edit: add some screenshot to understand better:
[image: eureka form]
[image: MultipleSelectorRow]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, I subclassed the original MultipleSelectorViewController in the following way:

```
import Foundation
import Eureka
import ChameleonFramework

public class MFAMultipleSelectorViewController<T:Hashable> : MultipleSelectorViewController<T> {

  open override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setTableViewBackgroundGradient(FlatMintDark(), FlatMintDark().lighten(byPercentage: 0.05)!)
  }
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor = ClearColor()
  }
}

open class _MFAMultipleSelectorRow<T: Hashable, Cell: CellType>: GenericMultipleSelectorRow<T, Cell, MFAMultipleSelectorViewController<T>> where Cell: BaseCell, Cell: TypedCellType, Cell.Value == Set<T> {
  public required init(tag: String?) {
    super.init(tag: tag)
  }
}

public final class MFAMultipleSelectorRow<T: Hashable> : _MFAMultipleSelectorRow<T, PushSelectorCell<Set<T>>>, RowType {
  public required init(tag: String?) {
    super.init(tag: tag)
  }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Use the [default cell customizer](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/blob/master/Example/Example/ViewController.swift#L1084).

```
LabelRow.defaultCellUpdate = { cell, row in
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .red
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = .white
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13)
    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .right
```

Comment: this doesn't interact with presented viewcontroller

Comment: `self.tableView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.green` this should solve your problem (tested, and everything is green now)

Comment: Inside which callback? I think that you're talking about the form and not about the multiple selection viewcontroller that is presented after tap

Comment: Oh probably yes... sorry... my mistake.

Comment: btw I found a solution :)